# mongoDB find, update and pull in One Query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to do all the find the data from the collection and then want to update some field as well as depending on want to empty the array.

```
const addCityFilter = (req, res) => {
  if (req.body.aCities === "") {
    res.status(409).jsonp({ message: adminMessages.err_fill_val_properly });
    return false;
  } else {
    var Cities = req.body.aCities.split(","); // It will make array of Cities
    const filterType = { "geoGraphicalFilter.filterType": "cities", "geoGraphicalFilter.countries": [], "geoGraphicalFilter.aCoordinates": [] };
    /** While using $addToset it ensure that to not add Duplicate Value
     * $each will add all values in array
     */
    huntingModel
      .update(
        {
          _id: req.body.id,
        },
        {
          $addToSet: {
            "geoGraphicalFilter.cities": { $each: Cities }
          }
        },
        {$set:{filterType}},
      ).then(function(data) {
        res.status(200).jsonp({
          message: adminMessages.succ_cityFilter_added
        });
      });
  }
};
```

**Collection**

```
geoGraphicalFilter: {
    filterType: {
      type:String,
      enum: ["countries", "cities", "polygons"],
      default: "countries"
    },
    countries: { type: Array },
    cities: { type: Array },
    aCoordinates: [
      {
        polygons: { type: Array }
      }
    ]
  }
```

But as result, the only city array is getting an update. No changes in `filterType`.

Comment: Because that's `{ "$addToSet": { ... }, "$set": { ... } }`. Your wrong syntax is `{ "$addToSet: {.. } }, { "$set": { ... } }`. Se the `.update()` signature [`update(<query>,<update>,<options>)`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#db.collection.update). So the `<update>` is **one document**, where you put in in separate documents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be passing the `$set` of `filterType` as the options argument, not the update argument.

```
huntingModel
  .update(
    {
      _id: req.body.id,
    },
    {
      $addToSet: {
        "geoGraphicalFilter.cities": { $each: Cities }
      },
      $set: {
        filterType
      }
    }
  ).then(function(data) {
    res.status(200).jsonp({
      message: adminMessages.succ_cityFilter_added
    });
  });
```